# Как сделать полосу прокуртки для таблицы?

Tags: css

У меня есть проект. Одностраничник.

Таблица, которая генерится на странице выползает за рамки экрана на маленьких экранах.
Я хочу пофиксить это. Как сделать скролл таблицы? Я пытался использовать `overflow: scroll;` для `.main-table`, но у меня ничего не получилось...

[Ссылка на стили](https://github.com/remenok200/Collatz-conjecture/blob/master/assets/css/style.css).

Comment: Вот это чтоль? https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: Может хотя-бы часть вашего кода добавить что-бы было легче понять вашу проблему и помочь в её решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно обернуть TABLE в отдельный DIV и уже этому DIV'у задать overflow: scroll;